# Por que a cor GREY é mais escura que DARKGREY?

Tags: css

Quando usamos [palavras chaves de cor](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#palavras-chave_de_cores)  para definir uma propriedade CSS, podemos escolher cores pelo nome. O que me irrita muitas vezes é que a cor grey/gray é visivelmente mais escura que a cor darkgrey/darkgray, o que para mim não faz sentido.

Por que essa diferença?

PS: Eu não quis dizer só "visivelmente", pois tecnicamente isso é uma verdade.
O hexadeximal de gray é #808080 enquanto que darkgray é #a9a9a9, ou seja, a cor branca (#ffffff) está mais próxima de darkgray do que de gray.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

p {
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1;
}

div p:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: darkgray;
  color: white;
}

div p:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white
}

div p:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>CINZA ESCURO (darkgray)</p>
  <p>CINZA (gray)</p>
  <p>CINZA CLARO (lightgray)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: _"... o que para mim não faz sentido."_ Frase que eu mais escutei sobre desenvolvedores back-end quando tiveram que trabalhar CSS XD. Resposta curta: Por que a W3C [definiu assim.](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/color/keywords). Motivo: não sei. Vou esperar por uma reposta bem explicativa também :)

Comment: Como está o perfil de cores do seu monitor?